# Replace attr link with fadeIn - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to fadeIn new loading page when click on that particular link. I tried below jQuery. Current page fadeOut works, but fadeIn not works for newly loading page.

```
$('.navbar ul li a').click(function(e) {
    $('.navbar').animate({'width': 'toggle'});
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    var destination = $(this).data("link");
    $("body").fadeOut(1000,function(){
       window.location.replace(link);
    }).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a logical problem here:

```
    window.location.replace(link);
```

loads a new page, so every code after it is not being executed (this includes the `.fadeIn()`)

Maybe you have to find a different way to replace the content *inside* your body, instead of replacing the whole page

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. I expect exactly new page should load with fadeIn effect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the fadein JS to the new page on load. For that it needs to have `opacity: 0` applied to its body (via CSS), which can then be transitioned to full visibiliity.

If the fadein should only happen when coming from that previous page, you can use a `GET` parameter in the URL of the link which is checked on load. If it's there, apply the opacity transition, if not, change opacity to 1 immediately in that script.